# Pervasive Control Center SQL INTO Error

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I am getting an error in PCC which doesn't make a lot of sense. I have two statements inside a user defined function that are nearly exactly the same and one runs fine while the other is returning an error:

'INTO': Syntax error

end and start are parameters being passed to the function.

The Error is being thrown on the second INTO statement

```
SELECT count(*) INTO :divModelTot1
FROM "table1"."info" i
WHERE i.compldate <:end
AND (i.agree is null OR i.agree>:start)
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) INTO :divModelTot2
FROM "table2"."info" i
WHERE i.compldate <:end
AND (i.agree is null or i.agree>:start);
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently taking out the INTO statement and leaving it as SELECT count(*) takes the error away, is there a rule against using INTO statements and UNIONS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT INTO must be the first query in a statement containing a UNION.

```
SELECT count(*) INTO :divModelTot1
FROM "table1"."info" i
WHERE i.compldate <:end
AND (i.agree is null OR i.agree>:start)
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*)
FROM "table2"."info" i
WHERE i.compldate <:end
AND (i.agree is null or i.agree>:start);
```